# C++ Linux Multithread Socket Issue

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, sockets, client

This is code of a client a friend sent me. I have little knowledge of socket programming. It is meant to be somewhat like a chat client; sends text to server and server sends it to all clients. I edited it where is displays colored text on execution with instructions on chat commands. The issues are the /ls command will be recognized and not send to the server as intended for the time being but it wont do anything instructed within the **else if** statement. Secondly, after using a command or sending text to the server it wont let me use a command or send text anymore. I can type but nothing goes through to the server and I do not get receive the typical e.g. "Received bytes 12" message; Except after I use the /dis command to disconnect from the server but I it says "Received Bytes -1" of course. Any ideas or advice? Thanks in advance.

I also provided the server source at the bottom incase someone thinks theres a problem there.

**Client Source**

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#define ANSI_COLOR_RED     "\x1b[31m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_GREEN   "\x1b[32m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW  "\x1b[33m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BLUE    "\x1b[34m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA "\x1b[35m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_CYAN    "\x1b[36m"

#define ANSI_COLOR_BRIGHT  "\x1b[1m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_RESET   "\x1b[0m"

using namespace std;

int main(int argv, char** argc){

    string olr = "Global" ANSI_COLOR_RESET;
    string help = ANSI_COLOR_CYAN "\n\n/help for a list of commands e.g help\n/ls to list online chat rooms e.g. /ls\n/j namehere to join a chat room. e.g. /j Global\n/p namehere -e codehere to private chat. e flag for encryption;\n\tnot required. e.g. /p Sunny got the dox?\n/tp to toggle receiving private messages or not e.g /tp\n/l codehere to listen for encrypted private messages. Seperate \n\tmultiple codes with a comma (,). e.g. /l 123,1234\n/st to stop listening for any encrypted messages e.g /st\n/c namehere to create a chat room. e.g. /c Journalism\n/clr to clear the screen e.g. /clr\n/dis to disconnect from the server e.g. /dis\n/con to connect to the server e.g. /con\n" ANSI_COLOR_RESET;
    int host_port= 1604;
    char* host_name="127.0.0.1";

    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;

    char buffer[1024];
    int bytecount;
    int buffer_len=0;

    int hsock;
    int * p_int;
    int err;

    hsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(hsock == -1){
        printf("Error initializing socket %d\n",errno);
    }

    p_int = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p_int = 1;

    if( (setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1 )||
        (setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char*)p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1 ) ){
        printf("Error setting options %d\n",errno);
        free(p_int);
    }
    free(p_int);

    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(host_port);

    memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host_name);

    if( connect( hsock, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) == -1 ){
        if((err = errno) != EINPROGRESS){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting socket %d\n", errno);

        }
    }
    printf(ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA "\nOnline Rooms: ");
    printf(olr.c_str());
    printf(help.c_str());
    //Now lets do the client related stuff
    while (true){
    buffer_len = 1024;
    string pokemon;
    pokemon = "/dis";
    memset(buffer, '\0', buffer_len);
    fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin);
    buffer[strlen(buffer)-1]='\0';
    stringstream ss;
    string bufferstr;
    ss << buffer;
    ss >> bufferstr;
    if (bufferstr == pokemon){
        close(hsock);
    }

    else if (bufferstr == "/help"){
        printf(help.c_str());
    }

    else if (bufferstr == "/ls"){
        printf("Online Rooms: " );
        printf(olr.c_str());
    }

    else if((bytecount=send(hsock, buffer, strlen(buffer),0))== -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending data %d\n", errno);
    }

    //what happens after sent
    //printf("Sent bytes %d\n", bytecount);

    if((bytecount = recv(hsock, buffer, buffer_len, 0))== -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data %d\n", errno);
    }
    printf("Recieved bytes %d\nReceived string \"%s\"\n", bytecount, buffer);
    }
    //close(hsock);

}
```

**Server Source**

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* SocketHandler(void*);

int main(int argv, char** argc){

    int host_port= 1604;

    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;

    int hsock;
    int * p_int ;
    int err;

    socklen_t addr_size = 0;
    int* csock;
    sockaddr_in sadr;
    pthread_t thread_id=0;


    hsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(hsock == -1){
        printf("Error initializing socket %d\n", errno);
      //  goto FINISH;
    }

    p_int = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p_int = 1;

    if( (setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1 )||
        (setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char*)p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1 ) ){
        printf("Error setting options %d\n", errno);
        free(p_int);
      //  goto FINISH;
    }
    free(p_int);

    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(host_port);

    memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY ;

    if( bind( hsock, (sockaddr*)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) == -1 ){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error binding to socket, make sure nothing else is listening on this port %d\n",errno);
     //   goto FINISH;
    }
    if(listen( hsock, 10) == -1 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error listening %d\n",errno);
//        goto FINISH;
    }

    //Now lets do the server stuff

    addr_size = sizeof(sockaddr_in);

    while(true){
        printf("waiting for a connection\n");
        csock = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        if((*csock = accept( hsock, (sockaddr*)&sadr, &addr_size))!= -1){
            printf("---------------------\nReceived connection from %s\n",inet_ntoa(sadr.sin_addr));
            pthread_create(&thread_id,0,&SocketHandler, (void*)csock );
            pthread_detach(thread_id);
        }
        else{
            fprintf(stderr, "Error accepting %d\n", errno);
        }
    }

FINISH:
;
}

void* SocketHandler(void* lp){
    int *csock = (int*)lp;

    char buffer[1024];
    char pokemon[3];
    int buffer_len = 1024;
    int bytecount;

    int ignore;
    pokemon[0] = '/';

    if (buffer[0] == pokemon[0]){
        ignore = 1;
    } else {ignore = 0;}

    memset(buffer, 0, buffer_len);
    if((bytecount = recv(*csock, buffer, buffer_len, 0))== -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data %d\n", errno);
        //goto FINISH;
    }
    printf("Received bytes %d\nReceived string \"%s\"\n", bytecount, buffer);
    strcat(buffer, " SERVER ECHO");

    if (ignore==0) {
        if((bytecount = send(*csock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0))== -1){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error sending data %d\n", errno);
            //  goto FINISH;
        }
    }

    printf("Sent bytes %d\n", bytecount);

//FINISH:
  //  free(csock);
    //return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read more about [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) and [event loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). See also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). Compile with `g++ -Wall -g` (or  `gcc -Wall -g` for *C* code). Learn how to **use the `gdb` debugger**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess from your code is that you are just blocking on this call:
bytecount = recv(hsock, buffer, buffer_len, 0))== -1

A blocking call (or synchronous) is a call to function that will not return unless it completes, since you are saying 'hey receive 1024 bytes on this socket', the function will not return unless it finds 1024 bytes or an 'eom', if that socket is empty, you will wait there forever.

For further info on recv(...) and how to make it non-blocking see: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/recv.html

Hope this helps, I didn't run the code, just that call seems suspicious.

After you posted your server code, there is a big bug:
`SocketHandler` is the entry point for your thread (it's like the 'main' of your main process), but it has no loop in it, your thread exits after one receive-send and then noone is listening to that socket in the server side. You need to add a while loop  like the one in the client to your server handler.

Also, for future reference, try not to name your variables 'pokemon' is really distracting and makes it harder for other people to guess what that variable is supposed to do.

Comment: I commented out if statement including the recv call and the two prints under it. I can use my commands fine now! After typing something such as "Hi" though the info wont send to the server again. Any ideas on this?

Comment: That has to do with the second part of my answer:
Your thread is only executing 'SocketHandler' one time and then exiting (dying, going kaput) so every time you send a message it gets into the socket, but nobody is listening for that message in the server (that was your thread's job, and now he's dead, just like Zed baby). You need to enclose the thread main function in a while(true){...} loop, to be sure the thread rec's a message, processes it, does whatever it needs to do, and then goes back to listening for new messages.